# Undefined reference to fp_init() Using fprint in Qt

Tags: qt, undefined, fingerprint

I am trying to use the libfprint in my Qt application

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <libfprint/fprint.h>    

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int r = 1;
    struct fp_dscv_dev *ddev;
    struct fp_dscv_dev **discovered_devs;
    struct fp_dev *dev;
    struct fp_print_data *data;

    r = fp_init();

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Compiling throws this error

> /concept/main.cpp:31: undefined reference to `fp_init()'

I have been battling with this for a while now. Any idea what I can do to get past this point? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you coding in C because you like it or because libfprint? You can use Eric Python IDE to build graphical applications really fast, and write a small program in C to take care of fingerprint handling. You can use popen to call this C program. I hope someone write a python wrapper soon.

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem with your linker - it cannot find necessary libraries. Did you pass necessary linker switches (something like `-lfoo`) instructing it to link with library you are trying to use?

Comment: I'm using QT Creator to the build  the application. Is there a place to specify this?

Comment: Forgot to mention this  - fprint.h was written in C, and using extern "C" to wrap it does not make any difference

Comment: Yes, in your .pro file. You must add something like LIBS += -lfprint